# What does syntax error 'unexpected tPOW' mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is an error, I getting in Rails project on launch attempt:

```
syntax error, unexpected tPOW (SyntaxError)
...           -> comment, item, **options { polymorphic_url [it...
...                               ^
```

What does it mean? For some reason I can't even find tPOW on google!

Just to clarify, project is not mine, so figuring out what some parts do. In this case errors were in this piece of code:

```
  post:             -> comment, item, **options { polymorphic_url [item.blog, item, comment], options },
  user_file:        -> comment, item, **options { user_file_url item, :comments, comment.id, options },
  attachment:       -> comment, item, **options { url_for [item, comment] },
  wall_inscription: -> comment, item, **options { user_wall_inscription_comment_url item.user, item, comment, options }
```

Comment: Check if this is related https://stackoverflow.com/a/34480810/4758119

Comment: What version of Ruby is this? 1.9.X perhaps? The `**` keyword splat is being interpreted as a power/exponent operator.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3. The thing is that project is not even mine, so I'm trying to figure out what certain parts of it do.

Comment: `tPOW` means the token that expresses power, namely `**`. It has nothing to do with Mario Brothers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the issue was in version 1.9.3 which was using json version 2.3.0

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/json-2.3.0/lib/json/common.rb:156: syntax error, unexpected tPOW, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
    Parser.new(source, **(opts||{})).parse
```

The fix that worked for me was to use an older version of json

```
gem uninstall json #Uninstall all installed versions
gem install json -v 1.8.6 # Define version
```